# How to process live sound output

Tags: audio, kernel

I'm new to android and new to anything related to soundprocessing.

The thing is, I have a simple deep learning model to eliminate noise (barking dogs, cars, ...). I want to apply (use) it to the sound output on android phone (ex: when I call messenger, the sound comes from my friend have barking, I will turn on my app to get rid of dog barking, I will turn on my app to eliminates dog barking) but I don't know how to do it. I have found an architecture on Windows that shows where my model is located:
[image]

On picture display shows both incoming and outgoing sound for a conversation, It adopts the driver and IOCTL protocol to interfere with the transfer of sound from user mode to the kernel and vice versa, is it the same in android? . Can someone tell me how it looks in android or any information, I've seen something [here](https://source.android.com/devices/audio) but for a novice like me it's too little information. Thank everybody!

Comment: As you already pointed out the diagram is for Windows and thus can't be applied to Android. Furthermore on Android you can't install drivers or system components. Please note that app development and ROM development is considered off-topic here. This community focuses on Android (power) users, not developers.

Comment: @Robert Thank you so much